# Django and Ajax based model saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

via ajax, I want to post some data and if model successfully gets saved, returns answer as a JSON object.

Here is my jquery based ajax post:

```
var requestData = { 'ievent_id': type , 'channel_id': CHANNEL_ID , 'start_date': dateToStrConverter(start_date) , 'end_date': dateToStrConverter(end_date) };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my-ajax-url/",
    data: requestData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log( "ID:" + data.plan_id + " Error:" + data.error);
    },
    error: function(msg){
        alert( "Theres an error with the server." );
    }              
});
```

And my Django view that handles this ajax call to save iEventPlan objects and return response:

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json

def planner_save_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        root = json.loads(request.raw_post_data[0])

        ##data
        ievent = iEvent.objects.get(pk = root['ievent_id'])
        channel = Channel.objects.get(siservice = root['channel_id'])
        start_date = datetime.strptime(root['start_date'],'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(root['end_date'],'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
        response_dict = {}
        try:
            plan = iEventPlan(red_button=ievent,channel=channel,start_date=start_date,end_date=end_date)
            plan.save()
            response_dict.update({'plan_id': plan.id})
        except:
            response_dict.update({'error': "theres a problem."})
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict), mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        HttpResponse("Not authorized.")
```

This is the error I get:

```
JSONDecodeError at /my-ajax-url/

No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

What I am doing wrong? I will be grateful if you show me the proper way of handling ajax based django model savings and responses.

Comment: I think the last line of this code needs to be:

    return HttpResponse("Not authorized.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending POST data in the standard form encoding. The `dataType` attribute doesn't specify type of data to send, but the one you expect to **receive**. If you really want to send JSON from your browser, you should do something like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    // other options
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.ajax()` function doesn't post data as raw JSON. It uses the standard form-encoded format (the `dataType` parameter is to determine what format it is expecting the *response* from the server).

So instead of the `json.loads()` call, you should just do this:

```
root = request.POST
```